# psycopg2.extras.DictRow behaves differently using for vs. next

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

This is v2.8.5 running in python 3.8.5. The following works as expected:

```
  curs = pgconn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
  curs.execute("select fid from A")
  for row in curs:                                                   
    print(row['fid'])
```

but this does not:

```
  row = next(curs, None)                                             
  print(row['fid'])                                                       

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/extras.py", line 168, in __getitem__
    x = self._index[x]
KeyError: 'fid'
```

The type of `row` is `<class 'psycopg2.extras.DictRow'>` in both cases.

Obvious pilot error somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

`psycopg2.extras.DictRow` already implements/wraps your `next(...)` calls and comes with a `__inter__` function which prepares and filles the `DictRow` ([source](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/fbba461052ae6ebc43167ab69ad91cadb7914c83/lib/extras.py#L107)).

As you can see in the implementation of a `_build_index` function it populates an `OrderedDict`.
Looping over the cursor, creates an (filled) `_index` for each `DictRow`:

```
pgconn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mf port=5959 host=localhost user=mf_usr")
curs = pgconn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

curs.execute("select * from users where id > 366200 and id < 366203")

for r in curs:
    print(r._index)
```

Out:

```
OrderedDict([('id', 0), ('firstname', 1), ('lastname', 2), ('birth', 3), ('ua', 4), ('nationality', 5)])
OrderedDict([('id', 0), ('firstname', 1), ('lastname', 2), ('birth', 3), ('ua', 4), ('nationality', 5)])
```

Using `next(...)` from the 'outside', behaves strange and does not use `__iter__`, so you end up with an empty index, so the `KeyError` drops in:

```
...
curs.execute("select * from users where id > 366200 and id < 366203")

row = next(curs, None)
print(row._index)
```

Out:

```
OrderedDict()
```

Comment: Good explain.   Is the answer then to use `fetchone`?

Comment: Use your for-loop: `for row in curs: print (row['fid')]`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use `for` because the calling logic controls the loop, not this segment which just gets the next row.   And I already have a generator doing a `yield` on top of all of it.

Answer (score 0):

`DictCursor` is a  hybrid structure:

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html

"
class psycopg2.extras.DictCursor(*args, **kwargs)

A cursor that keeps a list of column name -> index mappings
"

Try with `RealDictCursor` which returns an actual dictionary:

"
class psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor(*args, **kwargs)

A cursor that uses a real dict as the base type for rows.

Note that this cursor is extremely specialized and does not allow the normal access (using integer indices) to fetched data. If you need to access database rows both as a dictionary and a list, then use the generic DictCursor instead of RealDictCursor.
"

As example:

```
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=production host=localhost user=postgres", cursor_factory=RealDictCursor) 

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from cell_per")
next(cur)["cell_per"]
18
```

Comment: I do wish to access rows as a dict and a list, and generic `DictCursor` does work in the `for row in cursor:` context.  The question is why doesn't it work in the `next(cursor)` context when both yield the same object.

Comment: See @Maurice Meyer answer.  Another option is to use curs.fetchone().